# Drum exercise BPM do not add up

Tags: recreational-mathematics

This will be an oversimplified question for most of you so please pardon my ignorance in advance.

I practice 16th note exercises in which each rhythm, or 16 bars, is practices 20 times each and there are a total of 24 sections of 16 note rhythms. The metronome is set to 152 beats per minute. I was curious and decided to do the math.

Where is my math wrong below?

(16 x 20)  = 320 beats per section
(24 x 320) = 7,680 total beats in the 24 sections
(7,680 / 152) = 50 <- This is how long the math is telling me it would take to finish all sections at 152 beats per minute.

I finish the exercise in around 24 minutes, not 50. I know the answer is simple and probably relates to my warped notion of beat per minute.

@152 beats per minute

```
1 [ !!!! !!!! !!!! !!!! ] 16 x 20 times
2 [ !!!! !!!! !!!! !!!! ] 16 x 20 times
3 [ !!!! !!!! !!!! !!!! ] 16 x 20 times
...
24[ !!!! !!!! !!!! !!!! ] 16 x 20 times
```

Comment: How many beats do you use per bar?

Comment: @maxmilgram - 16. A bar looks like this = [ !!!! !!!! !!!! !!!! ]

Comment: That's not 16 bars, that's 16 sixteenth notes per bar, i.e., 4/4 time.

Comment: Yes, but how many metronom beats are there in one bar?

Comment: @maxmilgram - hmmm. The metronome is set to 152 bmp. My though was to add all the beats up and divide by the bpm.

Comment: @SeanRoberson - Thanks for the correcting my boggled my musical terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trombonist here.

Assuming each bar is in $\frac{4}{4}$ time, we have $16 \cdot 4 = 64$ quarter note beats per phrase. Each phrase is repeated $20$ times, for a total of $64 \times 20 = 1280$ quarter notes. Now your metronome is set to $152$ BPM (i.e., quarter-note 152), so doing this exercise completely should take $\frac{1280}{152} \approx 8.42$ minutes.

Your mistake is treating each sixteenth note as a beat - unless, of course, your time signature is $\frac{k}{16}$. That requires a difference calculation.

Comment: Doh! I see my error. Each sixteenth note is measured as a beat, not each beat of a sixteenth note?

Comment: Correct. Note, however, that if you're playing in, say, $\frac{9}{16},$ each sixteenth note counts as a beat. This computation assumes the rhythms are in common time.

Comment: If I measure each 16th note as a beat in 4/4 time then I get 4x20=80 and 80x24=1920 and 1920 / 152 = 12, however, I finish in 24 minutes. It could be the difference in drum notes but weird.  I have never considered the mathematical component to playing an instrument.

Comment: First - "If I measure each 16th note as a beat in 4/4 time..." No. It's no longer 4/4 time if you use a 16th note as the basis of a beat. Second - I encourage you to try the computation with something simpler, say, 60 BPM, and convince yourself that the numbers are the way they should be.

Comment: Doh, you were right. I was incorrectly referring to 16th notes while in fact it was 4/4 bars of quarter notes.